# Read azure active directory custom domains from asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am working on a c# asp.net application where i need to read all the custom domains from azure active directory as shown in the image below.

[image]

Can anyone kindly guide me to the msal sdk so that i can access the custom domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using Microsoft Graph API

To return a collection of [domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/domain?view=graph-rest-1.0) objects,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains
```

**C# Code Sample,**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var domains = await graphClient.Domains
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Please go to [Step-by-Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core)  guide which can help you in the implementation.